# Resizing issue in Python w tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, resize

So I made a calculator with tkinter and I used the .place method to put my buttons on the screen and to make it resizable I did anchor CENTER but now the bottom buttons are touching the edge of the window and every time I change the geometry of y instead of it working as a bottom padding, it takes the buttons with it [here's how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwLmM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Actually without your code I am unable to understand your problem

but
you can try the following :-

```
from tkinter import*



class Calculator:

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        self.root = Tk()

        self.root.geometry("550x644")

        self.root.title("My Calculator")

        self.root.resizable(0,0)


        self.total_expression = ""

        self.current_expression = ""

        self.display_frame = self.displayframe()

        self.total_label,self.label = self.display_label()

        self.button_frame = self.buttonframe()

        for j in range(1,5):

            self.button_frame.rowconfigure(j, weight=1)

            self.button_frame.columnconfigure(j, weight=1)

        self.operators = {"/":"\u00F7","*":"\u00D7","-":"-","+":"+"}

        self.digit = {

            7:(2,1), 8:(2,2), 9:(2,3),

            4:(3,1), 5:(3,2), 6:(3,3),

            1:(4,1), 2:(4,2), 3:(4,3),

            0:(5,2), ".":(5,3)

        }

        self.button()

        self.create_operator()

        self.specialbutton()

        self.bind_key()

    def backspacebuttonf(self):

        self.current_expression = self.current_expression[0:len(self.current_expression) -1]

        if self.current_expression == "":

            self.current_expression = "0"

        self.update_label()

    def backspacebutton(self):

        button = Button(self.button_frame, text="<=", bg="white", borderwidth=0, font="Impact 20", command=self.backspacebuttonf)

        button.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=NSEW)

    def bind_key(self):

        self.root.bind("<Return>",lambda event: self.evaluation())

        self.root.bind("<BackSpace>",lambda event: self.backspacebuttonf())

        for key in self.digit:

            self.root.bind(str(key), lambda event,digit=key: self.add_to_expression(digit))

        for key in self.operators:

            self.root.bind(key, lambda event, operator=key: self.append_operator(operator))

    def specialbutton(self):

        self.equal()

        self.clear()

        self.square()

        self.sqrt()

        self.backspacebutton()

        self.half()

        self.clearE()

        self.buttn()

        self.negative()

    def add_to_expression(self, value):

        self.current_expression += str(value)

        self.update_label()

    def append_operator(self, operator):

        self.current_expression += operator

        self.total_expression += self.current_expression

        self.current_expression = ""

        self.update_label()

        self.update_total_label()

    def displayframe(self):

        frame = Frame(self.root, height=251, bg="white")

        frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

        return frame

    def display_label(self):

        total_label = Label(self.display_frame, text=self.total_expression,anchor=E,bg="white", fg="grey",font="Impact 16", padx=24, pady=24, borderwidth=0)

        total_label.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

        label = Label(self.display_frame, text=self.current_expression,anchor=E,bg="white", font="Impact 40", padx=24, pady=24, borderwidth=0)

        label.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

        return total_label,label

    def buttonframe(self):

        frame = Frame(self.root, bg="light grey")

        frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

        return frame

    def create_operator(self):

        i = 1

        for operator,symbol in self.operators.items():

            button = Button(self.button_frame, text=symbol, borderwidth=0, font="Arial 15 bold", bg="white",fg="black", command=lambda j=operator: self.append_operator(j))

            button.grid(row=i, column=4, sticky=NSEW)

            i+=1

    def clearf(self):

        self.total_expression = ""

        self.current_expression = ""

        self.update_total_label()

        self.update_label()

    def clear(self):

        button = Button(self.button_frame, text="C", bg="white", fg="black", font="Arial 15 bold", borderwidth=0, command=self.clearf)

        button.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=NSEW)

    def buttnf(self):

        self.current_expression = "0"

        self.total_expression = "0"

        self.update_label()

        self.update_total_label()

    def buttn(self):

        button = Button(self.button_frame, text="%", bg="white", fg="black", font="Arial 15 bold", borderwidth=0, command=self.buttnf)

        button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NSEW)

    def clearEf(self):

        

        self.current_expression = ""



        self.update_label()

    def clearE(self):

        button = Button(self.button_frame, text="CE", bg="white", fg="black", font="Arial 15 bold", borderwidth=0, command=self.clearEf)

        button.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=NSEW)

    def squaref(self):

        try:

            self.current_expression = str(eval(f"{self.current_expression}**2"))

            self.update_label()

        except Exception as e:

            self.current_expression = "Error"

            self.update_label()

    def square(self):

        button = Button(self.button_frame, text="x\u00b2", bg="white", fg="black", font="Arial 15", borderwidth=0, command=self.squaref)

        button.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=NSEW)

    def halff(self):

        try:

            self.current_expression = str(eval(f"1/{self.current_expression}"))

            self.update_label()

        except Exception as e:

            self.current_expression = "Error"

            self.update_label()

    def half(self):

        button = Button(self.button_frame, text="1/x", bg="white", fg="black", font="Arial 15", borderwidth=0, command=self.halff)

        button.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=NSEW)

    def sqrtf(self):

        try:

            self.current_expression = str(eval(f"{self.current_expression}**0.5"))

            self.update_label()

        except Exception as e:

            self.current_expression = "Error"

            self.update_label()

    def sqrt(self):

        button = Button(self.button_frame, text="\u221ax", bg="white", fg="black", font="Arial 15", borderwidth=0, command=self.sqrtf)

        button.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=NSEW)

    def equal(self):

        button = Button(self.button_frame, text="=", bg="light blue", fg="black", borderwidth=0, font="Arial 20 bold", command=self.evaluation)

        button.grid(row=5, column=4, sticky=NSEW)

    def nagetivef(self):

        if "-" in self.total_expression:

            self.total_expression = str(self.total_expression.replace("-",""))

            self.update_total_label()

        else:

            self.total_expression = str(f"-{self.total_expression}")

            self.update_total_label()

    def negative(self):

        button = Button(self.button_frame, text="+/-", bg="white", fg="black", borderwidth=0, font="Arial 20", command=self.nagetivef)

        button.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=NSEW)

    

    def button(self):

        for digit,grid_value in self.digit.items():

            button = Button(self.button_frame, text=str(digit), bg="white", borderwidth=0, font="Arial 15 bold", fg="black", command=lambda j=digit: self.add_to_expression(j))

            button.grid(row=grid_value[0], column=grid_value[1], sticky=NSEW)

    def evaluation(self):

        self.total_expression+=self.current_expression

        try:

            self.current_expression = str(eval(self.total_expression))

            self.total_expression = ""

            with open("History.txt","w") as f:

                f.write(self.current_expression)

            self.update_total_label()

        except Exception as e:

            self.current_expression = "Error"

        self.update_label()

    def update_total_label(self):

        expression = self.total_expression

        for operator,symbol in self.operators.items():

            expression = expression.replace(operator,f"{symbol}")

            self.total_label.config(text=expression)

    def update_label(self):

        self.label.config(text=self.current_expression[:11])

    def run(self):

        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    calc = Calculator()

    calc.run()
```